# Выдаёт несуществующую ошибку в юнити

Tags: c#, android, unity3d

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using UnityEngine;

public class FonChange : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject tres1;
    public GameObject max1;
    public GameObject doge1;
    public int trees;
    public int maxx;
    public int dogee;

    void Start()
    {
        int trees = 1;
        int maxx = 0;
        int dogee = 0;
        tres1.SetActive(true);
        max1.SetActive(false);
        doge1.SetActive(false);
    }

    void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        if (int trees = 1)
        {
            trees--;
            maxx++;
        }
        else if (int maxx = 1) {
                maxx--;
                dogee++;
            }
        else if (int dogee = 1) {
                dogee--;
                trees++;
            }
        
    }    
    void Update()
    {
        if (trees = 1)
        {
            tres1.SetActive (true);
            max1.SetActive (false);
            doge1.SetActive (false);
        }
        else if (maxx = 1)
        { 
            max1.SetActive (true); 
            tres1.SetActive (false);
        }
        else if (dogee = 1)
        {
            doge1.SetActive (true);
            max1.SetActive (false);
        }
    }
}
```

выдает ошибку что нету "}" (37,31), что делать?

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! несвязанные вопросы следует задавать **отдельными** вопросами. оставьте, пожалуйста, один вопрос, внеся правку (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса)

Comment: Ответ уже дали, но это вам определенно стоит почитать : https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/2.24.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что делать? Учить работу условий)

Оператор `a = b` **присваивает** переменной `a` значение из `b` и **не может** использоваться как выражение. В вашем же случае вам нужно **сравнить** 2 числа с помощью оператора **сравнивания**: `a == b`, который возвращает `true` если значения переменных `a` и `b` идентичны

А так же вы создаёте новые переменные в методе `Start()`, а вам же надо просто присвоить им другое значение

Вот переписанный код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using UnityEngine;

public class FonChange : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject tres1;
    public GameObject max1;
    public GameObject doge1;
    public int trees = 1;
    public int maxx = 0;
    public int dogee = 0;

    void Start()
    {
        tres1.SetActive(true);
        max1.SetActive(false);
        doge1.SetActive(false);
    }

    void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        if (trees == 1)
        {
            trees--;
            maxx++;
        }
        else if (maxx == 1) 
        {
            maxx--;
            dogee++;
        }
        else if (dogee == 1) 
        {
            dogee--;
            trees++;
        }
        
    }    
    void Update()
    {
        if (trees == 1)
        {
            tres1.SetActive (true);
            max1.SetActive (false);
            doge1.SetActive (false);
        }
        else if (maxx == 1)
        { 
            max1.SetActive (true); 
            tres1.SetActive (false);
        }
        else if (dogee == 1)
        {
            doge1.SetActive (true);
            max1.SetActive (false);
        }
    }
}
```